# MySQL - Convert rows into columns based on latest date and list of ids for each column

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot-table, greatest-n-per-group, groupwise-maximum

I still can't figure this out even after hours of searching and trying. Maybe I did not choose the right words?

Okay, so I have table with events like this:

```
EVENT
+----+------------+------------+------+
| id | id_article | id_section | date |
+----+------------+------------+------+
|  1 |          1 |          1 | 2011 |
|  2 |          1 |          3 | 2012 |
|  3 |          2 |          7 | 2013 |
|  4 |          2 |          6 | 2014 |
|  5 |          3 |         14 | 2015 |
|  6 |          3 |         13 | 2016 |
|  7 |          3 |          0 | 2017 |
+----+------------+------------+------+
```

I would like to pivot this table into three different columns where each column contains latest events (*id_section* and *date*) within list of *id_section*. Well, basically like this:

**sectionA** = id_section IN (1,2,3,4,5) and MAX(date)

**sectionB** = id_section IN (6,7,8,9,10) and MAX(date)

**sectionC** = id_section IN (11,12,13,14,15) and MAX(date)

```
DESIRED RESULT
+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| id_article | sectionA | sectionB | sectionC  | #id_event
+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
|          1 | 3 (2012) | null     | null      | #id 2
|          2 | null     | 6 (2014) | null      | #id 4
|          3 | 0 (2017) | null     | 13 (2016) | #id 7, 6 <-- two latest events
+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

Here is [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5dcf8/12) of what I have right now - it only selects latest event per *id_article*:

```
INSUFFICIENT RESULT
+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
| id_article | sectionA | sectionB | sectionC  | #id_event
+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
|          1 | 3 (2012) | null     | null      | #id 2
|          2 | null     | 6 (2014) | null      | #id 4
|          3 | 0 (2017) | null     | null      | #id 7 <-- only latest event
+------------+----------+----------+-----------+
```

I tried to use more JOINS but I still can't figure it out.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: And if there are ties?

Comment: @GordonLinoff then maybe choose that with higher id (event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

based on your current query, i did some changes on the subquery to identify the max if there are multiple sections on each id_article. also, 0 should be included in the list for SectionA

```
SELECT e1.id_article, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'SectionA' 
                THEN CONCAT(e2.id_section, ' (', e2.date, ')') END) AS sectionA, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'SectionB' 
                THEN CONCAT(e2.id_section, ' (', e2.date, ')') END) AS sectionB, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN section = 'SectionC'
                THEN CONCAT(e2.id_section, ' (', e2.date, ')') END) AS sectionC
  FROM event e1
 INNER JOIN (SELECT a.id_article,
                    a.id_section,       
                    a.`date`,
                    a.section,
                    COUNT(*) row_number
               FROM (SELECT *,
                            CASE WHEN id_section IN (0,1,2,3,4,5)
                                 THEN 'SectionA'
                                 WHEN id_section IN (6,7,8,9,10)
                                 THEN 'SectionB'
                                 WHEN id_section IN (11,12,13,14,15)
                                 THEN 'SectionC'
                             END section
                       FROM `event`) a
              INNER JOIN  (SELECT *,
                                  CASE WHEN id_section IN (0,1,2,3,4,5)
                                       THEN 'SectionA'
                                       WHEN id_section IN (6,7,8,9,10)
                                       THEN 'SectionB'
                                       WHEN id_section IN (11,12,13,14,15)
                                       THEN 'SectionC'
                                   END section
                             FROM `event`) b
                 ON a.id_article = b.id_article
                AND a.section = b.section
                AND a.`date` <= b.`date`
              GROUP BY a.id_article,
                       a.id_section,       
                       a.`date`
            ) e2
    ON e1.id_article = e2.id_article 
   AND e1.date = e2.date
 WHERE e2.row_number = 1
 GROUP BY e1.id_article
```

Result

```
id_article  sectionA    sectionB    sectionC
1           3 (2012)    (null)      (null)
2           (null)      6 (2014)    (null)
3           0 (2017)    (null)      13 (2016)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  
(yes I forgot about the zero)

Comment: Is it possible to somehow create a view with this? I need this as a datasource for grid in php? :)